Git to azure migration error "Push was rejected because size greater than 5120 MB"
I am trying to migrate git to Azure but getting below error
"TF402462 The push was rejected because size was greater than 5120 MB"
My repo size is 9.8Gb in that actual repo is 100mb and .git folder is 9.8GM.

I tried GIt LFS by givng below command
git lfs migrate import --everything --include=".zip,.a,.tar,.dll,.lib,.xz,.bz2,.exe,.ttf,.ttc,.db,.mp4,.tgz,.pdf,.dcm,.so,.pdb,.msi,.jar,.bin,*.sqlites"
THis command sucessfully completed and finally i gave "git push --mirror" which shown error "TF402462 The push was rejected because size was greater than 5120 MB" after runnign for few hours.
Looks like some push in remote is greater than 5GB limit but I am not able to see any commit like that. How can we solve this.

Complete guess here, but it appears that the push limit is 5GB, but not the repo itself. As long as there isn't a single commit that adds more than 5GB of changes, then I suppose you could push commits in sets. Maybe push the first 100 commits, than the second 100, etc. You could manually bisect and try pushing the first half of the repo, and keep halving until it succeeds, then get another chunk, etc. With a 9.8 GB repo you can assume you'll need at least 2 pushes.

Side notes: my previous comment applies to a repo that isn't using LFS. I don't know if the answer changes when you are using LFS. Also, since you're migrating, consider if you even need all the huge history or not. This might be the best to time purge some of the history, if applicable.

(I just noticed the push was rejected after running for a few hours, so it isn't calculating up front and rejecting immediately. In that case, perhaps you could calculate how big each set of commits' push will be before trying.)

How can we find size of each commit?. I used git push --mirror, how to push commits set by set

If possible can you please share your code repo?

Finding commit size isn't necessarily straight forward, but it's possible.
